# How get a row by 4 first chars?

Tags: python, mysql

I need to get a row by condition 4 first chars. I try to input manually, its work. but, when i use format. it got **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1**.

in fruits field. there're **banana**, **labanana**, **lobanana**. i need to retrieve **banana**. then let **labanana** and **lobanana** not get retrieve.

```
con = mysql.connect(
  host="127.0.0.1",
  user="localhost",
  passwd="localhost",
  database='foods'
)

cursor = con.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `eat` WHERE SUBSTR(fruits, 1, 4) = %s", ('bana'))
```

Comment: Please include the Python code you used to obtain your cursor.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen as you said. i include it. I use same ways to format in INSERT and UPDATE. but SELECT not work.

Comment: "not work" is practically useless in describing the behavior that is observed. Is there an error message, an exception, no result returned, unexpected results returned, ...

Comment: Try removing backticks  at "eat".

Comment: @Dev backticks around a table name is valid MySQL (granted not needed though).

Comment: @spencer7593 it so confusing here. if i put manuall the value and replace %s with bana. it works.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , Sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correctly using a prepared statement, but your need to obtain a cursor with statement mode enabled.  Try this version:

```
con = mysql.connect(
    host = "127.0.0.1",
    user = "localhost",
    passwd = "localhost",
    database = 'foods'
)

cursor = con.cursor(prepared=True)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `eat` WHERE SUBSTR(fruits, 1, 4) = %s", ('bana',))
```

Comment: Same here. mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s'

Comment: @yuiamanda A minor but perhaps important change to my answer: pass the tuple of parameters as `('bana',)` with a comma after the first (and only) element.

Comment: @yuiamanda It has to do with that `('bana')` is not being interpreted by Python as a tuple, but rather something else.  By placing the trailing comma, you are telling Python that it is a tuple.